# How to implement "Do you want to save changes?" dialog for a text editing program in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, text-editor

I have written a text editing program similar to Notepad in C++ with the Qt framework. It only has basic functionality such as Undo, Redo etc. I want to show a dialog which will show up if the user hasn't saved his changes and ask whether he/she wants to save the changes similar to the one in Notepad and other such programs. How should I proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt's [documentation for QMessageBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#the-property-based-api) discusses this and provides the following example: -

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("The document has been modified.");
msgBox.setInformativeText("Do you want to save your changes?");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Save);
int ret = msgBox.exec();

switch (ret) {
  case QMessageBox::Save:
      // Save was clicked
      break;
  case QMessageBox::Discard:
      // Don't Save was clicked
      break;
  case QMessageBox::Cancel:
      // Cancel was clicked
      break;
  default:
      // should never be reached
      break;
}
```

Applications can monitor when they're about to quit via the [aboutToQuit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal, which is where you would prompt the user.

For example ([with C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake/19398489#19398489))

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;

    // Note Qt 5 connect syntax with C++ 11 lambda function
    QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, [&w](){

        qDebug() << "Terminating - Goodbye!\n";

        //Display msg prompt here
        if(QMessageBox::question(NULL, "Test", "Save?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes)
        {
            // if result is save...
            w.save();
        }
    });

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: How will I check whether the document has been saved first. Only if the document isn't saved, this dialog should popup.

Comment: If you're using `QTextDocument`, you can use its [changed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#contentsChanged) signal, else you'll have to monitor that yourself. Then, maintain a boolean flag, which you set to false when the document is loaded. With any change made, set it to true, then after saving, set it back to false.

Comment: How do I implement the Cancel function if I am to use your example?

Comment: If you want to cancel the closing of the application, you can check for saving in the [closeEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480984/qt-how-do-i-handle-the-event-of-the-user-pressing-the-x-close-button) of the MainWindow, instead of the main function.

Comment: Thanks @TheDarkKnight for your advice. When I finish my program, I will try to send a copy of it to you.

Comment: `aboutToQuit` cannot be used here, see the docs: "The signal is particularly useful if your application has to do some last-second cleanup. Note that no user interaction is possible in this state."

closeEvent needs to be overridden to be able to say "no, don't quit".

Comment: @exscape, thanks for pointing out the documentation, but a QMessageBox does work in this instance. Try it for yourself, before marking down the answer.

Comment: It wouldn't work if you want to have "cancel" as an option, and applications that don't are pretty user-unfriendly.

Comment: @exscape, the question being asked isn't requesting whether or not cancelling the quit operation is an option. It asks how to prompt the user to save changes before the quit occurs.

Comment: I'm aware, but such a dialog should IMO always have the cancel option. Every well-designed application allows you to cancel the shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
        Document unsaveDocument = getUnsaveDocument();
        if (unsaveDocument.isModified()) {
           QMessageBox *alert = new QMessageBox;
           alert->setWindowTitle("File is modified");
           alert->setText("Do you want to save your changes?");
           alert->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
           alert->setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Save);
           int ret = alert->exec();
           alert->deleteLater();
           if (ret == QMessageBox::Save) {
               saveDocument();
           } else {
               doSomeThing(); //When discard or cancel
           }
       }
```